# Nintendo Switch emulator log analysis Discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first attempt at open source contribution via a Python discord bot, built to analyse user-uploaded log files and give quick, at-a-glance information for support staff.

The PR is here: https://github.com/Ryujinx/ryuko-ng/pull/3

My main concerns are:

- Is this structured properly?
- What could I improve? I've attempted to make use of things like list comprehensions instead of relying too much on regex, but sometimes it's unavoidable.
- I've been reading into things like decorators, and wondering if they could be used here, but I've not grasped how to use them, or if they're even applicable here.

Without further ado:

````py
import logging
from typing import Type
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
import re
import aiohttp
import config

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s (%(levelname)s) %(message)s (Line %(lineno)d)",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
)


class LogFileReader(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        # Allows log analysis in #support and #patreon-support channels respectively
        self.bot_log_allowed_channels = config.bot_log_allowed_channels
        self.uploaded_log_filenames = []

    async def download_file(self, log_url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            # Grabs first and last few bytes of log file to prevent abuse from large files
            headers = {"Range": "bytes=0-25000, -6000"}
            async with session.get(log_url, headers=headers) as response:
                return await response.text("UTF-8")

    async def log_file_read(self, message):
        self.embed = {
            "hardware_info": {
                "cpu": "Unknown",
                "gpu": "Unknown",
                "ram": "Unknown",
                "os": "Unknown",
            },
            "emu_info": {
                "ryu_version": "Unknown",
                "ryu_firmware": "Unknown",
                "logs_enabled": None,
            },
            "game_info": {
                "game_name": "Unknown",
                "errors": "No errors found in log",
                "mods": "No mods found",
                "notes": [],
            },
            "user_settings": [
                {
                    "pptc": "Unknown",
                    "audio_backend": "Unknown",
                    "docked": "Unknown",
                    "vsync": "Unknown",
                }
            ],
        }
        attached_log = message.attachments[0]
        author_name = f"@{message.author.name}"
        log_file = await self.download_file(attached_log.url)
        # Large files show a header value when not downloaded completely
        # this regex makes sure that the log text to read starts from the first timestamp, ignoring headers
        log_file_header_regex = re.compile(r"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}.*", re.DOTALL)
        log_file = re.search(log_file_header_regex, log_file).group(0)

        def get_hardware_info(log_file):
            try:
                self.embed["hardware_info"]["cpu"] = (
                    re.search(r"CPU:\s([^;\r]*)", log_file, re.MULTILINE)
                    .group(1)
                    .rstrip()
                )
                self.embed["hardware_info"]["ram"] = (
                    re.search(r"RAM:(\sTotal)?\s([^;\r]*)", log_file, re.MULTILINE)
                    .group(2)
                    .rstrip()
                )
                self.embed["hardware_info"]["os"] = (
                    re.search(r"Operating System:\s([^;\r]*)", log_file, re.MULTILINE)
                    .group(1)
                    .rstrip()
                )
                self.embed["hardware_info"]["gpu"] = (
                    re.search(
                        r"PrintGpuInformation:\s([^;\r]*)", log_file, re.MULTILINE
                    )
                    .group(1)
                    .rstrip()
                )
            except AttributeError:
                pass

        def get_ryujinx_info(log_file):
            try:
                self.embed["emu_info"]["ryu_version"] = [
                    line.split()[-1]
                    for line in log_file.splitlines()
                    if "Ryujinx Version:" in line
                ][0]
                self.embed["emu_info"]["logs_enabled"] = (
                    re.search(r"Logs Enabled:\s([^;\r]*)", log_file, re.MULTILINE)
                    .group(1)
                    .rstrip()
                )
                self.embed["emu_info"]["ryu_firmware"] = [
                    line.split()[-1]
                    for line in log_file.splitlines()
                    if "Firmware Version:" in line
                ][0]
            except (AttributeError, IndexError):
                pass

        def format_log_embed():
            cleaned_game_name = re.sub(
                r"\s\[(64|32)-bit\]$", "", self.embed["game_info"]["game_name"]
            )
            self.embed["game_info"]["game_name"] = cleaned_game_name

            hardware_info = "\n".join(
                (
                    f"**CPU:** {self.embed['hardware_info']['cpu']}",
                    f"**GPU:** {self.embed['hardware_info']['gpu']}",
                    f"**RAM:** {self.embed['hardware_info']['ram']}",
                    f"**OS:** {self.embed['hardware_info']['os']}",
                )
            )

            user_settings_info = "\n".join(
                (
                    f"**Audio Backend:** `{self.embed['user_settings'][0]['audio_backend']}`",
                    f"**Console Mode:** `{self.embed['user_settings'][0]['docked']}`",
                    f"**PPTC:** `{self.embed['user_settings'][0]['pptc']}`",
                    f"**V-Sync:** `{self.embed['user_settings'][0]['vsync']}`",
                )
            )

            ryujinx_info = "\n".join(
                (
                    f"**Version:** {self.embed['emu_info']['ryu_version']}",
                    f"**Firmware:** {self.embed['emu_info']['ryu_firmware']}",
                )
            )

            log_embed = discord.Embed(
                title=f"{cleaned_game_name}", colour=discord.Colour(0x4A90E2)
            )
            log_embed.set_footer(text=f"Log uploaded by {author_name}")
            log_embed.add_field(name="Hardware Info", value=hardware_info)
            log_embed.add_field(name="Ryujinx Info", value=ryujinx_info)
            if cleaned_game_name == "Unknown":
                log_embed.add_field(
                    name="Empty Log",
                    value="""This log file appears to be empty. To get a proper log, follow these steps:
                        \n 1) Start a game up.
                        \n 2) Play until your issue occurs.
                        \n 3) Upload your log file.""",
                    inline=False,
                )
            log_embed.add_field(
                name="Settings",
                value=user_settings_info,
                inline=False,
            )
            log_embed.add_field(
                name="Latest Error Snippet",
                value=self.embed["game_info"]["errors"],
                inline=False,
            )
            log_embed.add_field(
                name="Mods", value=self.embed["game_info"]["mods"], inline=False
            )
            log_embed.add_field(
                name="Notes",
                value="\n".join(game_notes),
                inline=False,
            )

            return log_embed

        def analyse_log(log_file):
            self.embed["game_info"]["game_name"] = (
                re.search(
                    r"Loader LoadNca: Application Loaded:\s([^;\r]*)",
                    log_file,
                    re.MULTILINE,
                )
                .group(1)
                .rstrip()
            )
            for setting in self.embed["user_settings"]:
                # Some log info may be missing for users that use older versions of Ryujinx, so reading the settings is not always possible.
                # As ['user_setting'] is initialized with "Unknown" values, False should not be an issue for setting.get()
                try:
                    switch_mode = [
                        line.split()[-1]
                        for line in log_file.splitlines()
                        if "IsDocked" in line
                    ][-1]
                    if switch_mode and setting.get("docked"):
                        setting[
                            "docked"
                        ] = f"{'Docked' if switch_mode == 'True' else 'Handheld'}"

                    pptc_setting = re.search(
                        r"Ptc Initialize:.+\(enabled:\s(.+?)\)[^;\r]",
                        log_file,
                        re.MULTILINE,
                    ).group(1)
                    if pptc_setting and setting.get("pptc"):
                        setting[
                            "pptc"
                        ] = f"{'Enabled' if pptc_setting == 'True' else 'Disabled'}"

                    audio_setting = [
                        line.split()[-1]
                        for line in log_file.splitlines()
                        if "AudioBackend" in line
                    ][-1]
                    if audio_setting and setting.get("audio_backend"):
                        setting["audio_backend"] = audio_setting

                    # Take note of the difference between 'Vsync' and 'VSyncStatus' capitalization in both initial and toggle settings
                    vsync_setting = [
                        line.split()[-1]
                        for line in log_file.splitlines()
                        if "Vsync" in line or "VSyncStatus_Clicked" in line
                    ][-1]
                    if vsync_setting and setting.get("vsync"):
                        setting[
                            "vsync"
                        ] = f"{'Enabled' if vsync_setting == 'True' else 'Disabled'}"
                except (AttributeError, IndexError) as error:
                    print(f"User settings exception: {logging.warn(error)}")
                    continue

            def analyse_error_message(log_file):
                try:
                    errors = []
                    curr_error_lines = []
                    for line in log_file.splitlines():
                        if line == "":
                            continue
                        if "|E|" in line:
                            curr_error_lines = [line]
                            errors.append(curr_error_lines)
                        elif line[0] == " " or line == "":
                            curr_error_lines.append(line)
                    shader_cache_collision = bool(
                        [
                            line
                            for line in errors
                            if any("Cache collision found" in string for string in line)
                        ]
                    )
                    last_errors = "\n".join(
                        errors[-1][:2] if "|E|" in errors[-1][0] else ""
                    )
                except IndexError:
                    last_errors = None
                return (last_errors, shader_cache_collision)

            # Finds the lastest error denoted by |E| in the log and its first line
            # Also warns of shader cache collisions
            last_error_snippet, shader_cache_warn = analyse_error_message(log_file)
            if last_error_snippet:
                self.embed["game_info"]["errors"] = f"```{last_error_snippet}```"
            else:
                pass

            if shader_cache_warn:
                shader_cache_warn = f"⚠️ Cache collision detected. Investigate possible shader cache issues"
                self.embed["game_info"]["notes"].append(shader_cache_warn)

            def mods_information(log_file):
                mods_regex = re.compile(r"Found mod\s\'(.+?)\'\s(\[.+?\])")
                matches = re.findall(mods_regex, log_file)
                if matches:
                    mods = [{"mod": match[0], "status": match[1]} for match in matches]
                    mods_status = [
                        f"ℹ️ {i['mod']} ({'ExeFS' if i['status'] == '[E]' else 'RomFS'})"
                        for i in mods
                    ]
                    return mods_status

            # Find information on installed mods
            game_mods = mods_information(log_file)
            if game_mods:
                self.embed["game_info"]["mods"] = "\n".join(game_mods)
            else:
                pass

            controllers_regex = re.compile(r"Hid Configure: ([^\r\n]+)")
            controllers = re.findall(controllers_regex, log_file)
            if controllers:
                input_status = [f"ℹ {match}" for match in controllers]
                # Hid Configure lines can appear multiple times, so converting to dict keys removes duplicate entries,
                # also maintains the list order
                input_status = list(dict.fromkeys(input_status))
                input_string = "\n".join(input_status)
            else:
                input_string = "⚠️ No controller information found"
            self.embed["game_info"]["notes"].append(input_string)

            try:
                ram_avaliable_regex = re.compile(r"Available\s(\d+)(?=\sMB)")
                ram_avaliable = re.search(ram_avaliable_regex, log_file)[1]
                if int(ram_avaliable) < 8000:
                    ram_warning = "⚠️ Less than 8GB RAM avaliable"
                    self.embed["game_info"]["notes"].append(ram_warning)
            except TypeError:
                pass

            if "Darwin" in self.embed["hardware_info"]["os"]:
                mac_os_warning = "**❌ macOS is currently unsupported**"
                self.embed["game_info"]["notes"].append(mac_os_warning)

            if "Intel" in self.embed["hardware_info"]["gpu"]:
                if (
                    "Darwin" in self.embed["hardware_info"]["os"]
                    or "Windows" in self.embed["hardware_info"]["os"]
                ):
                    intel_gpu_warning = "**⚠️ Intel iGPUs are known to have driver issues, consider using a discrete GPU**"
                    self.embed["game_info"]["notes"].append(intel_gpu_warning)

            # Find information on logs, whether defaults are enabled or not
            default_logs = ["Info", "Warning", "Error", "Guest", "Stub"]
            user_logs = (
                self.embed["emu_info"]["logs_enabled"]
                .rstrip()
                .replace(" ", "")
                .split(",")
            )
            disabled_logs = set(default_logs).difference(set(user_logs))
            if disabled_logs:
                logs_status = [f"⚠️ {log} log is not enabled" for log in disabled_logs]
                log_string = "\n".join(logs_status)
            else:
                log_string = "✅ Default logs enabled"
            self.embed["game_info"]["notes"].append(log_string)

            if self.embed["emu_info"]["ryu_firmware"] == "Unknown":
                firmware_warning = f"**❌ Nintendo Switch firmware not found**"
                self.embed["game_info"]["notes"].append(firmware_warning)

            def severity(log_note_string):
                symbols = ["❌", "⚠️", "ℹ", "✅"]
                return next(
                    i for i, symbol in enumerate(symbols) if symbol in log_note_string
                )

            game_notes = [note for note in self.embed["game_info"]["notes"]]
            ordered_game_notes = sorted(game_notes, key=severity)

            return ordered_game_notes

        get_hardware_info(log_file)
        get_ryujinx_info(log_file)
        game_notes = analyse_log(log_file)

        return format_log_embed()

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        if message.author.bot:
            return

        # If message has an attachment
        try:
            author_mention = message.author.mention
            filename = message.attachments[0].filename
            # Any message over 2000 chars is uploaded as message.txt, so this is accounted for
            log_file_regex = re.compile(r"^Ryujinx_.*\.log|message\.txt$")
            is_log_file = re.match(log_file_regex, filename)
            if message.channel.id in self.bot_log_allowed_channels and is_log_file:
                if filename not in self.uploaded_log_filenames:
                    reply_message = await message.channel.send(
                        "Log detected, parsing..."
                    )
                    try:
                        embed = await self.log_file_read(message)
                        if "Ryujinx_" in filename:
                            self.uploaded_log_filenames.append(filename)
                            # Avoid duplicate log file analysis, at least temporarily; keep track of the last few filenames of uploaded logs
                            # this should help support channels not be flooded with too many log files
                            # fmt: off
                            self.uploaded_log_filenames = self.uploaded_log_filenames[-5:]
                            # fmt: on
                        return await reply_message.edit(content=None, embed=embed)
                    except UnicodeDecodeError:
                        return await message.channel.send(
                            f"This log file appears to be invalid {author_mention}. Please re-check and re-upload your log file."
                        )
                    except Exception as error:
                        await reply_message.edit(
                            content=f"Error: Couldn't parse log; parser threw {type(error).__name__} exception."
                        )
                        print(logging.warn(error))
                else:
                    await message.channel.send(
                        f"The log file `{filename}` appears to be a duplicate {author_mention}. Please upload a more recent file."
                    )
            elif not is_log_file:
                return await message.channel.send(
                    f"{author_mention} Your file does not match the Ryujinx log format. Please check your file."
                )
            else:
                return await message.channel.send(
                    f"{author_mention} Please upload log files to {' or '.join([f'<#{id}>' for id in self.bot_log_allowed_channels])}"
                )
        except IndexError:
            pass


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(LogFileReader(bot))
````